# Show the text value of a column based on the max of another

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a dataset where each entry is a book register. One of the columns is the title and, among others, there is a column for the publishing year. I want to create a measure/card that shows the name of the newest and oldest.

I've used:

```
Oldest = 
VAR old = MIN('Livros DB'[year])
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    VALUES ( 'Livros DB'[Title] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Livros DB'[year] ), 'Livros DB'[year] = old )
)
```

And this works for the oldest. However, it only works because there is only one entry with the same year. When I use the same solution for the newest, it fails, because there is more than just one entry for the same year. How could I return a list of the newest books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Newest = 
VAR new = MAX('Livros DB'[year])
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        CONCATENATEX( VALUES ( 'Livros DB'[Title] ), 'Livros DB'[Title], ","),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Livros DB'[year] ), 'Livros DB'[year] = new )
    )
```